# Slim error handling

Tags: php, slim

The Slim Framework is good - seriously good.  One of the issues I have run into is with the way it handles errors.  In vanilla PHP code I occasionally use trigger_error statements as a debug aid.  In vanilla PHP this has no untoward consequences since by default trigger_errors are E_USER_NOTICE type errors that do not stop the script dead in its tracks.  However, in Slim things appear to work differently.  A benign trigger_error causes it to throw a wobbly and an HTTP 500 is returned.

I thought this could be corrected by

1. Changing the *mode* to development or something but the docs state that this makes no difference whatsoever to the way Slim works internally.
2. Next port of call - changing the slim error logging level

   $app = new \Slim\Slim(array('log.level' => \Slim\Log::ERROR);

does not quite have the same effect as PHP's error_reporting.  Setting it stops the error from floating up to the error.log file (the default error logger used by Slim) but crucially it does **not** stop the HTTP 500.

I have come across forum posts that suggest replacing the default Slim::handleErrors method.  That would be easy but I wonder if that is not incorrect.  What is the right way to stop Slim coming to a dead halt when it runs into a wholly innocuous trigger_error?  I can well avoid this but I may rely on other code that may have such statements.  I would much appreciate any help

Comment: Hi, do you use the 'debug' flag?

Comment: how about putting trigger_error in a try/catch block? http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Helpers

Comment: @ruifn - merely changing the Slim mode - not even to debug -does nothing. Quoting from the Slim manual - Slim converts error into ErrorException instances...and If debugging is enabled, Slim will use its built-in error handler to display diagnostic information for uncaught Exceptions. If debugging is disabled, Slim will instead invoke your custom error handler, passing it the otherwise uncaught Exception as its first and only argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turns out to be quite simple.  I figured it out by checking out the *handleErrors* function in slim.php.  Just issue a

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_USER_WARNING);
```

prior to where the *trigger_error* is called and you are in business.  Somewhere down the line Slim is changing the default PHP error_reporting to include E_USER_WARNING.